# how can we compare and update the records in salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger

i have two objects that contain email fields and i have to compare two objects of records emailids if it matches email address update another field in contact by using of salesforce trigger.

```
 trigger emailmatchdatacontact on ContactRelationship__c (before insert,before update) 
{
  List<Contact> con= new List<Contact>();
    for(ContactRelationship__c cr:trigger.new)
    {
         Contact c=new Contact(); 
        if(cr.EmailId__c==c.Email)
        {
            cr.Name='divya';
            c.Opt_out_status__c=true;
            cr.ListofContacts__c=c.Id;
            con.add(c);
        }
    }
    update con;
}
```

Comment: you need to separately execute a query to retrieve Contact's email and then loop through to match email ids

Answer (score -1):

Try below code -

```
trigger emailmatchdatacontact on ContactRelationship__c (before insert,before update) {
    Map<String, Contact> mapOfEmailAndContact = new Map<String, Contact>();
    Set<string> emailSet = new Set<String>();

    for(ContactRelationship__c crVAr : Trigger.New){
      if(crVAr.Email__c != NULL){
        emailSet.add(crVar.Email__c);
      }
    }

    if(!emailSet.isEmpty()){
      for(Contact con : [SELECT ContactField__c, Email__c  FROM Contact WHERE Email__c IN : emailSet]){
          mapOfEmailAndContact.put(con.Email__c, con);
        }

        if(!mapOfEmailAndContact.isEmpty()){
          for(ContactRelationship__c crVAr : Trigger.New){
              if(mapOfEmailAndContact.containsKey(crVar.Email__c)){
                crVar.FieldToUpdate__c = mapOfEmailAndContact.get(crVar.Email__c).FieldOfContact__c;
                //add other field that you want to update on ContactRelation object.
              }
          }
        }

    }       
}
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation of what your changes are or what principles are in play here? "Code dump" answers don't help educate the asker or the community by themselves.